# How to properly apply a function to a series using series.map() or series.apply() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a predefined function (myfunc) to a new series in my DataFrame using pandas. The function will check if the value in each index in old column (for each row) is bigger then it's previous one and return 1 if yes and 0 if no.

I have also tried series.apply() function and I am getting:  across all rows in the newly created column.

```
def myfunc(x):
    for i in range(0,86):
        if x.iloc[i + 1] > x.iloc[i]:
            yield 1
        else:
            yield 0

df2['Higher Inflation - US'] = df2['US'].map(myfunc)
print(df2)
```

I expect to see 1's and 0's in the new column. I get the results I want when I use 'print' instead of 'yield' in my function, but what I want to do is apply this function to multiple series.

Comment: Can you just use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shift function to compare values in previous rows:

```py
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'US':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
})

def myfunc1(x):
    if x:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df2['Higher Inflation - US'] = (df2['US']>df2['US'].shift()).map(myfunc1)
df2
```

Will return:

```
    US  Higher Inflation - US
0   1   0
1   2   1
2   3   1
3   4   1
4   5   1
5   6   1
6   7   1
7   8   1
8   9   1
9   8   0
10  7   0
11  6   0
12  5   0
13  4   0
14  3   0
15  2   0
16  1   0
```

The function is so simple that it would be better to replace it with lambda:

```py
(df2['US']>=df2['US'].shift()).apply(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
```

The result is the same